# Can you use Ubuntu and Ubuntu Gnome (or more desktop enviorments) without dual booting?

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, kubuntu, ubuntu-gnome

I don't Know if this is possible, but can you use all of ubuntu and its derivitives (Xubuntu,Kubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Mate, Ubuntu Budgie, Ubuntu Studio) Without dual booting your computer?  Can you change them at any time?

Comment: You could also run VMs.

Answer (score 3):

Each of the distros you mentioned is in fact Ubuntu, just shipped with a different desktop environment.

You can install just one of them, then install the different Desktop Environments any time.

To install them, open a terminal, and run `apt-get install` with the appropriate package name. For example

GNOME Shell

```
    apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

MATE Desktop

```
    apt install mate-desktop-environment
```

Here is the list of several other Desktop Environments: [What kinds of desktop environments and shells are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

You can also search the Software Centre or Synamptic package manager if you have it installed, for "desktop environment".

Once installed, you will be able to choose one from your login screen, typically an icon representing the Desktop Environment will be available.

Comment: I Just use those codes for any desktop enviorment and that will work?

Comment: Yes it will work! Give them a try if you like one of them you can make a decision to change to that specific flavor